# Class 'MongoClient' not found in CentOS

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

PHP 5.5.22

PHP mongo driver already installed

See the `phpInfo()`

[image: mongodb extension]

In Terminal

```
$ php -i | grep 'Configuration File'
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/lib/php.ini

$ php -i | grep mongo
mongodb
mongodb support => enabled
mongodb version => 1.1.1
mongodb stability => stable
libmongoc version => 1.3.1-dev
mongodb.debug => no value => no value
```

But still, get this error

[image: MongoClient not found]

Any one faced this problem before? How you solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two mongo libraries for PHP

- [MongoDB driver (legacy)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php)  has MongoClient Class (marked as deprecated in PHP Docs) [Pecl Link](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongo)
- [MongoDB driver](http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php) The one you have installed doesn't have MongoClient Class. [Pecl Link](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb)

Check Mongo Driver the links to read the manuals they have different ways to connect.

Comment: Thanks. You're right, now I change to the legacy one, it works.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would try `composer self-update`

I had some problem regarding mongodb driver and composer before.

Then, check mongo.ini in your php config dir's conf.d subdir.
It should be `/etc/php/conf.d/mongo.ini`

What distro you use?

Comment: I don't have the `/etc/php/conf.d/mongo.ini` file

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, i had both `mongo` and `mongodb` installed with `pecl`, both added to php, and i restared apache afterwards. Still the same error. 
Solution: remove both and install them again, then reboot apache

```
pecl uninstall mongo
pecl uninstall mongodb
pecl install mongo
pecl install mongodb
if [ $(grep 'mongo.so' /etc/php.ini -c) -eq "0" ]; then echo "extension=mongo.so" >> /etc/php.ini ; fi
if [ $(grep 'mongodb.so' /etc/php.ini -c) -eq "0" ]; then echo "extension=mongodb.so" >> /etc/php.ini ; fi
service apache2 restart
```